# Xamarin Forms ListView with Image | Text | Time

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, hybrid

I am currently working with xamarin forms to build a hybrid app.
I am trying to build a listview that displays an error with an icon and a timestamp.

This is the concept design I want to remake into xamarin forms.
I used an `ImageCell` to try and get the icon with some text working but now that I want to add a third element (the time) above the icon (or next to the text, the PO is not sure about that)

[image]

Comment: use a ViewCell to build a custom layout instead

Comment: @Jason when building a custom `viewcell`, do I have to make a custom renderer for each platform I am building the app on or can xamarin handle this for me? (The docs do explain how to build one)

Comment: a ViewCell does not require a custom renderer.  It's just built out of regular XF elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jason said, you should use a `ViewCell`.

It would be like this:

```
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Image >
        </StackLayout>
        <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Add the other properties you need and your bindings and the cell is ready to use.

Comment: I would add that instead of the imagecell, awesome