# What do I need to do for activating ViewCell in XAML?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I would like to implement a custom ListView like here:
[Xamarin Forms ListView with Image | Text | Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535781/xamarin-forms-listview-with-image-text-time)

But the ViewCell-Element is not available in the toolbox of the visual designer in my Visual Studio installation. The designer is next to the XAML-Editor and can be used to Drag-n-Drop elements into views.

I think I also miss a lot of elements which have been available in the last years.

Visual Studio is up-to-date (VS 2017 15.9.6) and I updated everything in the SDK-Manager. I am only using API 27.

Is there a plugin or modul which I need to install?

EDIT: If I use the ViewCell in XAML I get following error while running the app and at function `SetContentView` with error message: `Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class ViewCell`

Comment: What tool box are you talking about your question is vague be specific

Comment: @G.hakim I have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: just type "<ViewCell ..." into your XAML, you don't have to drag it from the ToolBox

Comment: I don't personally think viewcells are dragable or altogether available in the toolbox , they come together with a listviee by default but in any case i don't use the toolbox so i wouldn't know!

Comment: @Jason I get following error: `Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class ViewCell`

Comment: are you using Xamarin Forms or Xamarin Android?  Is the file you're working with AXML or XAML?  There is a huge difference

Comment: @Snickbrack you are most likely using Xamarin.Android, where ViewCell does not exist.

Comment: I am working with Xamarin.android as the tags show. Is there an alternative in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: the tutorial your are following is for XAMARIN FORMS.  Android has it's own ListView control, which has ample documentation

Comment: @Snickbrack https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/recycler-view/

Answer (score 0):

**ViewCell is a part of the Xamarin.Forms Framework**

Xamarin.Forms is a cross-platform development tool allowing the building of native, cross-platform apps for Android, iOS, Windows, and others from a single shared C# codebase.,

Whereas Xamarin.Android is is an implementation of Mono that runs on the Android platform, allowing you to write Android applications in C# using native Android libraries as well as using the .NET BCL (Base Class Libraries).

Hence you cannot use ViewCell in Xamarin.Android, but you can use a ListView using the Xamarin Native Android API's and you can find an example of the same on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/)